# How can i adjust div position in tab container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `div` that only appears if I click a radio input. But after it shows it messes up my other radio buttons. How can I adjust it's position?

```
<!-- radio button code -->
<div id="chartDiv" style="display:none;" class="answer_list">Stĺpcový graf</div>
<input type="radio" name="grafy" value="graf5" onclick="showDiv()" />
```

(JavaScript function for `div` appearance after radio button is clicked)

```
function showDiv() {
     document.getElementById('chartDiv').style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: id page where div appears is "page-data-table"

Comment: Maybe "inline-block"

Comment: i already tried "inline_block" but it was the same

Comment: use style="max-width:inherit"

Comment: you need to reserve that space for the div in your css. Because the only thing I can see is that you want to show that div above the radios. There is an other option though. To put all the radio buttons inside a div and then the showDiv() function would only move the row or simply all the radios down. Nemas zac ;-)

Comment: I don't get your problem. Show whole code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `position:absolute` on to the div, this will mean it wont affect the layout of any other elements in the page.

```
<div id="chartDiv" style="display:none;position:absolute;" class="answer_list">
```

If that helps, you can then position the div using the top and left css properties.

```
 <div id="chartDiv" style="display:none; position:absolute; top:20px; left:20px;" class="answer_list">
```

You may also need to add `position:relative` to a parent element to make the `.answer_list` div position itself relative to that element.

```
 <div style="position:relative">
    <!--other elements radio buttons and so on-->
    <div id="chartDiv" style="display:none; position:absolute; top:20px; left:20px;" class="answer_list">
</div>
```